# ASP .NET Core: How to cache data which depend on user input?

Tags: c#, performance, web-services, caching, asp.net-core

We are building a new ASP.Net Core WebService which will provide data from existing Database.

To reduce to load on the database and improve response times I thought about caching certain objects and configurations from the database.

I found this for caching in ASP.Net Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2
What seems to be the way to go. The Article also says: *Do not use external input as cache keys*

My Problem now is that basically all data are depending on the user or a user input.

I am aware that caching makes only sense with objects that get often used but rarely changed. 
Here an simplified example when I might want to use caching: We do have holiday / workday configuration which can by per state different. So it can vary depending on the user but 100s of users  might use the same configuration.

Also there are some shared components which a lot of users share but which components are returned is depending on what is requested.

So what would be the best approach to cache such entities? 
I am also open for any Idea that helps me reduce the calls to the database.

Thanks and best regards,
Marc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding. The caution is against using external user input as cache *keys*. In other words, you should not take some input from the user and the set something in the cache via that:

```
_cache.SetString(userInput, "foo");
```

It's not talking about setting user input as the *value*, i.e.:

```
_cache.SetString("my cache key", userInput);
```

It's also not talking about segregating the cache by user:

```
_cache.SetString($"cache key for user {userId}", "foo");
```

Both of the latter scenarios are fine. It's just that allowing the user to set the key itself opens yourself up to things like potential SQL injection attacks, depending on your cache store.

Also, note that it's mostly talking about *unsanitized* user input. If it's something like an enum where the user can pick only from a set of defined values, then you're fine. Or, if you otherwise know that the input is not going to cause issues. For example, a zip code that you've validated only contains numbers and maybe a single dash. There's nothing a malicious user can do with that, so it's fine. However, a free form text field like "Name" would be problematic to say the least.

Comment: Thanks, that what I hopped to hear. So using primary keys of objects I want to caches is fine but I should not use string inputs in my keys?  That makes absolute sense.

Comment: Yes, basically just nothing as a key that isn't in some way under your control. It's either something you know will not be problematic, like a user id, or something that's been sanitized to the point where there can be no issue. Essentially the old caution for user input to guard against SQL injection. Most ORMs take care of that for you now, but cache keys can be a bit low-level, particular in things like Redis. The right control characters and a malicious user can do all kinds of things.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation discourages external input as cache keys, because it might lead to too many cache entries and consume quite a lot of RAM, which will in turn have negative impact on the performance.

You need to experiment.  Maybe you will not end up with too many different user input variations.

You can also consider an external caching service like [Memcached](https://www.memcached.org/), where you can use additional servers as cache.  This will allow you to cache many more values and reduce your load on the db.

Comment: Is the amount of entries really so relevant if I set proper size limits and cache priorities?
Of course I would still not cache everything.

Comment: Well, if you don't cache enough entries, the effect might be as if you don't cache anything.  :-)  Too many cache misses simply make the cache useless.